# group by in php to build a report

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table **USER** having the following columns

```
id,name
```

and another table **LISTING** having the following columns.

```
list_id,user_id,type
```

the LISTING table has multiple records for one user.  I run the following query using php to get listing for each user.

```
SELECT 
      USER.ID AS ID,
       NAME,
      TYPE (TYPE can be A or B)
   FROM
  USER,
  LISTING 
WHERE 
  LISTING.USER_ID = USER.ID 
  GROUP BY USER.ID
ORDER BY USER.ID DESC
```

Now,the problem is I want to show "BOTH" in my report if the USER has entries in LISTING table for TYPE a and b,ONLY A if there are no entries for the USER of type b and so on.

Please help!!

data:

**USER**  TABLE

```
+---+------
|id | name| 
+---+------
| 1 | jamy| 
| 2 | jazz|
| 3 |leo  | 
+---+-------
```

**LISTING** table

```
+---+------------+--------+
| id| user_id    |type    |
+---+------------+--------+
| 1 | 1          | A      |
| 2 | 2          | A      |
| 3 | 2          | B      |
| 4 | 3          | B      |
| 5 | 1          | A      |
+---+------------+-------+
```

NOW THE REPORT THAT I WANT SHOULD BE:

```
+---+------------+
|NAME| TYPE      |
+---+------------+
|JAMY| ONLY A    | 
|JAZZ| BOTH      | 
|LEO | ONLY B    | 
+---+------------+
```

Comment: Please, add samples of data - to clarify your request better

Comment: i have added the data samples hope they help!

Answer (score 0):

A `case` statement may be useful here, as well as some proper `join`s.

```sql
SELECT
  USER.ID AS ID,
  NAME,
  CASE
    WHEN X.USER_ID IS NOT NULL AND Y.USER_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'BOTH'
    WHEN X.USER_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'ONLY A'
    WHEN Y.USER_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'ONLY B'
    ELSE 'NEITHER'
  END AS TYPE
FROM USER
LEFT JOIN LISTING AS X ON X.USER_ID=USER.ID AND X.TYPE='A'
LEFT JOIN LISTING AS Y ON Y.USER_ID=USER.ID AND Y.TYPE='B'
ORDER BY USER.ID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need LEFT JOIN

```
  SELECT 
  USER.ID AS ID,
  NAME,
  TYPE 
  FROM USER LEFT JOIN LISTING 
  ON LISTING.USER_ID = USER.ID
  GROUP BY USER.ID
  ORDER BY USER.ID DESC
```